# Confidence interval for exponentially distributed estimator

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, estimators, exponential-distribution

We have an estimator $\hat{\theta}\geq 0$ for $\theta$, with distribution function $P\{\hat{\theta}\leq t \}=1-e^{-t/\theta}$, which we can recognize as the cdf of the exponential distribution. Our aim is to construct a 95% CI for  $\hat{\theta}$, and my first thoughts were to find the mean and variance, which I suppose would be $E(\hat{\theta})=\theta$ and $\text{Var}( \hat{\theta}) = \theta^2$, and then consider $\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\theta}\sim N(0,1)$, and construct a regular CI using this, however this does not seem to be correct. Any ideas as to what  I should do instead?

Comment: Hint: what is the distribution of $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}$?

Comment: @Joe Note that your quantity will only be asymptotically normal.   Have you heard of [pivotal quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity)?

Comment: @Glen_b I have, but I'm still quite stuck, since doesn't the distribution of the quantity depend on $\theta$?

Comment: @LucasPrates $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta} \sim N(1,\theta)$?

Comment: @Joe try obtaining the cdf for $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}$ by computing $\mathbb{P}(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta} \leq t)$.

Comment: @Joe a pivotal quantity is a random variable $X(\theta)$ in which its "expression" depends on $\theta$ but the distribution does not. Due to this, you can find the values $a$ and $b$ such that $\mathbb{P}(a \leq X(\theta) \leq b) = 1-\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the desired level, $5$% in your case. After you find these values, you re-express the inequality in terms of $\theta$, arriving at something like $c \leq \theta \leq d$, where $c$ and $d$ are the final values for the confidence interval.

Comment: @Joe If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. $\text{Exponential}(\theta)$ (scale parameterization as above), what's the distribution of $X_1+X_2$? What's the distribution of $(X_1+X_2)/2$? Can you generalize to $\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: @LucasPrates Okay so the distribution of $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}$ would be $\text{Exponential}(1)$, so this would be our pivotal quantity I suppose? Giving $P(a \leq \frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta} \leq b) = 1 - \alpha $, but I'm still struggling to see how we would choose both $a$ and $b$for a exponential distribution(one-sided), and also in general a bit confused as how one should notice that $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}$ is our pivotal quantity. Thanks again in advance guys, I'm pretty lost on this subject. Exam is up next week so really appreciate it.

Comment: Update: So I was thinking that we have $ P(a \leq \frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta} \leq b) = 1-\alpha$, then we also have $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}\leq a)=\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and  $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}\geq a)=\frac{\alpha}{2}$, which again would give us two equations using $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}\leq a) = 1-e^{-a} = \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}\geq b) = e^{-b}= \frac{\alpha}{2}$, which is easy to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Joe yes, you got the distribution correctly! Do not worry if it seems "strange" how you obtained the pivotal quantity, I agree that the process in general is a non-intuitive. I guess the best you can do for now is to practice obtaining pivotal quantities for distributions showed as examples in your course.

Comment: Yes, by solving those equations you will obtain a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval! Show us your solution for $a$ and $b$ if you can, it should be simple. However, after obtaining the values for $a$ and $b$, remember that $[a,b]$ is not yet a confidence interval for $\theta$ because you have $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\theta}$ in the middle! You will need to finalize by doing some algebraic operations and isolating $\theta$ on the middle, so you get a new interval $[c,d]$, where $c$ and $d$ depend on $a$, $b$ and $\hat{\theta}$. Post this final CI too if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I got $a=-\ln(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})$ and $b=-\ln(\frac{\alpha}{2})$, which in turn yielded $c=\frac{\hat{\theta}}{-ln(\frac{\alpha}{2})}$ and $d=\frac{\hat{\theta}}{-\ln(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}$

Comment: @Joe well done! Now, as a last challenge, imagine that, instead of asking an $1-\alpha$ CI of the form $c  \leq \theta \leq d$, you were asked to provide a CI of the form $0 \leq \theta \leq d$. That is, a finite one-tailed interval. How would you compute $d$? Or if it had the form $c \leq \theta \leq \infty$, how to compute $c$? Hint: its the same process, but in this case you will use $\alpha$ instead of $\frac{\alpha}{2}$.